# Why const_cast away volatile only work for pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, volatile, const-cast

```
// OK!
volatile CString* a0;
CString* a1 = const_cast<CString *>(a0);

// error C2440: 'const_cast' : cannot convert from 'volatile CString' to 'CString'
volatile CString b0;
CString b1 = const_cast<CString>(b0);
```

I was wondering, why `const_cast` only work for pointer? How can I make the 2nd case to compile?

Comment: @6502 No, it can also remove volatile (and apparently __unaligned although this might be an MS extension?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`const_cast` acts on pointers and references, to remove `const` and `volatile` qualifiers. It doesn't make sense to use it to cast to an object type, since then you would making a copy which need not have the same cv-qualifiers as the original anyway.

Your second example will compile if you cast to a non-volatile *reference*:

```
volatile CString b0;
CString & b1 = const_cast<CString &>(b0);
```

However, using that reference gives undefined behaviour, since the underlying object is itself `volatile`. You should only use `const_cast` to remove qualifications when you *know* that the underlying object does not have those qualifications (or in the case of removing `const`, when you *know* that the result won't be used to modify the object).

You can only get a copy if the object allows copying of volatile objects (perhaps with a copy constructor taking a reference-to-volatile or a volatile-qualified function or conversion operator). If `CString` doesn't provide any of these, then you can't safely copy a `volatile` object of that type.

Comment: For `CString b1 = b0;` to compile, one needs copy-ctor  of this form : `CString(CString volatile &)`. Right?

Comment: +1, but are you sure that removing a `volatile` and accessing is UB? For example what is UB is removing a const qualifier and **writing** to an object that is declared const, but just reading from it after removing the const qualifier is ok. Removing a `volatile` qualifier and access an object being sure that for example **no other threads are accessing it in that moment** (supposing this was the reason for `volatile`) I'd say that is also ok.

Comment: @6502: C++11 7.1.6.1/6 says "If an attempt is made to refer to an object defined with a volatile-qualified type through the use of a glvalue
with a non-volatile-qualified type, the program behavior is undefined." `volatile` has nothing to do with threads, except in some compilers with a non-standard extension that makes it also mean "atomic". It defines accesses to the object as visible side-effects of the program; removing the qualification can change those side-effects, and therefore change the program's behaviour in an undefined way.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Thanks, I learned something new. I always thought that volatile was used to just inform the compiler to make no assumption about it being a regular object with read-write semantic (e.g. to avoid making it assume that after writing something in it the value obtained by reading would be the same) and to respect write and read order. I wouldn't have classified for example reading from a volatile object using a non-volatile pointer UB (but just not necessarily respecting access order for example).

Comment: The moral of the story is that people who write classes usually make an effort to ensure that `const` instances of that class do something sensible, by providing `const` versions of non-mutating member functions, and taking arguments by `const MyClass &` where appropriate. They very rarely do anything similar for `volatile` instances. You might find that the only thing you can do with a `volatile` instance of many classes is destroy it, standard classes included.

Answer (score 0):

because in the second case you are actually copying `b0` and not referring to the original object

you need to do a reference in that case

```
const CString &b1 = b0;
```